# Alternative to a for loop for creating a streak column

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
 x <- data.frame("Name" = c("Jorge", "Jorge", "Jorge", "Tom", "Tom", "Jerry", "Tom", "Tom", "Jorge"),
                 "Date" = c("10-13-2017", "10-12-2017", "10-11-2017", "10-10-2017", "10-09-2017", 
                            "10-08-2017", "10-07-2017", "10-06-2017", "10-05-2017"))
```

I would like to make a column that count's the "Streak" that a name is in the name column.  The end result that I would like looks like this:

```
 Name       Date  Streak
 Jorge 10-13-2017      3
 Jorge 10-12-2017      2
 Jorge 10-11-2017      1
 Tom   10-10-2017      2
 Tom   10-09-2017      1
 Jerry 10-08-2017      1
 Tom   10-07-2017      2
 Tom   10-06-2017      1
 Jorge 10-05-2017      1
```

What I currently have is:

```
streak <- 1
for(i in NROW(x):2){

j <- i - 1

if(as.character(x[i, "Name"]) == as.character(x[j, "Name"])){
streak = streak + 1
x[i, "Streak"] = streak
}

else{
 x[i, "Streak"] = 1
 streak <- 1
}
}
```

This gives:

```
 Name       Date  Streak
 Jorge 10-13-2017      3
 Jorge 10-12-2017      3
 Jorge 10-11-2017      2
 Tom   10-10-2017      1
 Tom   10-09-2017      2
 Jerry 10-08-2017      1
 Tom   10-07-2017      1
 Tom   10-06-2017      2
 Jorge 10-05-2017      1
```

This is not right and I am struggling to figure out how to get the intended output.  Ideally I don't need to use a for loop because this is a large dataset with tens of thousands of rows, so it is very slow.

So my questions:

**1.**  Is there a way to do this without using a for loop?
**2.**  How do I start the counting from the bottom so that the output reflects the desired streak?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in base R with the `rle` function (run length encoding)...

```
x$Streak <- unlist(sapply(rle(as.character(x$Name))$lengths, seq, 1, -1))

x
   Name       Date Streak
1 Jorge 10-13-2017      3
2 Jorge 10-12-2017      2
3 Jorge 10-11-2017      1
4   Tom 10-10-2017      2
5   Tom 10-09-2017      1
6 Jerry 10-08-2017      1
7   Tom 10-07-2017      2
8   Tom 10-06-2017      1
9 Jorge 10-05-2017      1
```

This takes the run lengths of each name, generates a sequence counting down to one for each of them, then (by unlisting) turns them into a vector.

Answer (score 1):

We could use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(x)`), grouped by the run-length-id (`rleid`) of 'Name', get the reverse of sequence of number of rows and assign (`:=`) to create the 'Streak' column

```
library(data.table)
setDT(x)[, Streak := rev(seq_len(.N)), rleid(Name)]
x
#    Name       Date Streak
#1: Jorge 10-13-2017      3
#2: Jorge 10-12-2017      2
#3: Jorge 10-11-2017      1
#4:   Tom 10-10-2017      2
#5:   Tom 10-09-2017      1
#6: Jerry 10-08-2017      1
#7:   Tom 10-07-2017      2
#8:   Tom 10-06-2017      1
#9: Jorge 10-05-2017      1
```